# Bigquery mysql to adjust dates for active weekdays

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

In a previous question the answer was given to perform a query which would get revenue from the last year in a new column. This worked perfectly, but now I have a follow-up question. [(please review this link to have a look at the previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839534/bigquery-table-lead-column-values-based-on-date)

The query used to get this data (With thanks to [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221944/mikhail-berlyant)):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a.date, a.location, a.revenue, 
  DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) date_last_year, 
  IFNULL(b.revenue, 0) revenue_last_year 
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
ON a.location = b.location
AND DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) = b.date
```

The simplified outcome looks as follows (limited to 1 location):

```
date        revenue     revenue_last_year
2019-01-31  1471,2577   2185,406
2019-01-30  1291,1111   4723,7439
2019-01-29  2178,6532   2263,5283
2019-01-28  1531,8021   0
2019-01-26  1578,1247   2446,6234
2019-01-25  1299,644    1522,4537
2019-01-24  788,2669    1979,104
2019-01-23  787,441     4117,7927
2019-01-22  2437,2951   1876,2479
2019-01-21  1071,0476   0
2019-01-19  2291,0456   2289,8657
```

The follow up question relates to working with weekdays from last year. As you can see the revenue last year has '0' values. That's because it's a day that location A was closed. However, to make an accurate comparison on a day by day basis we need to locate the revenue for the day this revenue was open.

For more information, have a look at this table below to see what it looks like when we take the last 10 days of Jan this year and append two columns with the revenues of last year found manually:

```
date        revenue     revenue_last_year   date        revenue
2019-01-31  1471,2577   2185,406            2018-01-31  2185,406
2019-01-30  1291,1111   4723,7439           2018-01-30  4723,7439
2019-01-29  2178,6532   2263,5283           2018-01-29  2263,5283
2019-01-28  1531,8021   0                   2018-01-27  2843,6616
2019-01-26  1578,1247   2446,6234           2018-01-26  2446,6234
2019-01-25  1299,644    1522,4537           2018-01-25  1522,4537
2019-01-24  788,2669    1979,104            2018-01-24  1979,104
2019-01-23  787,441     4117,7927           2018-01-23  4117,7927
2019-01-22  2437,2951   1876,2479           2018-01-22  1876,2479
2019-01-21  1071,0476   0                   2018-01-20  2561,4086
2019-01-19  2291,0456   2289,8657           2018-01-19  2289,8657
```

Please note the differences in dates.

What would be a good way to solve this? Would it be necessary to adjust to a query for weekdays and how would you approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a.date, a.location, ANY_VALUE(a.revenue) revenue, 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(b.date AS date_last_year, b.revenue AS revenue_last_year) 
    ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
WHERE a.location = b.location
AND b.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY a.date, a.location
```

You can test, play with above using dummy/sample data (I used same as in my answer for your previous question) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-02-20' `date`, 'A' location, 1 revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-02-21', 'A', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-20', 'A', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-21', 'A', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-22', 'A', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-02-20', 'B', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-02-22', 'B', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-20', 'B', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-21', 'B', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-22', 'B', 10 
)
SELECT 
  a.date, a.location, ANY_VALUE(a.revenue) revenue, 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(b.date AS date_last_year, b.revenue AS revenue_last_year) 
    ORDER BY b.date DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table` a
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` b
WHERE a.location = b.location
AND b.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY a.date, a.location
-- ORDER BY a.date, a.location
```

with result

```
Row date        location    revenue date_last_year  revenue_last_year    
1   2019-02-20  A           5       2018-02-20      1    
2   2019-02-20  B           6       2018-02-20      2    
3   2019-02-21  A           7       2018-02-21      3    
4   2019-02-21  B           8       2018-02-20      2    
5   2019-02-22  A           9       2018-02-21      3    
6   2019-02-22  B           10      2018-02-22      4
```

Note the differences in dates :o)

Comment: Hi @Mikhail how would this work if you would go back 3 years instead of 1? It seems that the BETWEEN DATE does not work correctly anymore at that point.